# Add multiple links to string given delimiter

Tags: php

A have a string similar to this

```
$string='@[Carlos]({user}:529) is going to rock @[NEW YORK]({city}:111)';
```

the `@` indicates a tagged word exists, with the type and the `main_id`. My goal is to link the tagged words like this:

```
<a href="/user.php?id=529">@Carlos</a> is going to rock <a href="/city.php?id=111">@NEW YORK</a>
```

Once printed it will look as follows with links on Carlos and New York

> @Carlos is going to rock @NEW YORK

Using `substr_count` I would be able to know how many tags. I have a function to get a string between two delimiters

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
```

I'm stuck on how to approach this, any suggestions would help.

Comment: I would solve this with regular expressions.

Comment: preg_replace() (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) would seem the obvious function to use to handle everything in one function call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is in a nice format, perfect for regular expressions.

I'd use one that looked like this:

```
/@\[([\w\s]*)]\({(\w*)}:(\d*)\)/
```

This looks for an `@` sign, followed `[<words>]`, which is then followed by `({<word>}:<number>)`.

You can then use `preg_replace` to replace the strings with links, all at once.

```
$string = '@[Carlos]({user}:529) is going to rock @[NEW YORK]({city}:111)';
$regex = '/@\[([\w\s]*)]\({(\w*)}:(\d*)\)/';

$newString = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="/$2.php?id=$3">@$1</a>', $string);
```

DEMO: http://ideone.com/EYf4KR

Comment: Perfect makes clear sense, thanks for the quick reply and demo. much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions (preg_match/preg_match_all/preg_replace). Sample code :

```
<?php
$string='@[Carlos]({user}:529) is going to rock @[NEW YORK]({city}:111)';

print preg_replace('/@\[([^]]+)\]\(\{([a-z]+)\}:([0-9]+)\)/i', '<a href="/\2.php?id=\3">@\1</a>', $string);

?>
```

But you might want to use preg_replace_callback in order to do some htmlspecialchars() on the tag for security's sake. As well as urlencode() on the type. Like so :

```
function tag2url($matches) {
  $tag = $matches[1];
  $type = $matches[2];
  $id = $matches[3];
  return '<a href="/' . urlencode($type) . '.php?id=' . urlencode($id) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($tag) . '</a>';
}

print preg_replace_callback('/@\[([^]]+)\]\(\{([a-z]+)\}:([0-9]+)\)/i', "tag2url", $string);
```